# Apple mach-o linker error ("alignment lost")

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Not too sure what to make of this,

but program runs just fine in simulator. But when I test it on ipod/iphone i get the following...

```
Ld /Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swangle-iPhone-emtomlxdirhuoobwiveczqncivfw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Swangle-iPhone.app/Swangle-iPhone normal armv7
cd /Iphone/SDK/Swangle-iPhone
setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swangle-iPhone-emtomlxdirhuoobwiveczqncivfw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Iphone/SDK/Swangle-iPhone -F/Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swangle-iPhone-emtomlxdirhuoobwiveczqncivfw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swangle-iPhone-emtomlxdirhuoobwiveczqncivfw/Build/Intermediates/Swangle-iPhone.build/Debug-iphoneos/Swangle-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Swangle-iPhone.LinkFileList -dead_strip -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreData -lLexicontext -framework SenTestingKit -o /Users/MacBookPro/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Swangle-iPhone-emtomlxdirhuoobwiveczqncivfw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Swangle-iPhone.app/Swangle-iPhone
```

ld: warning: alignment lost in merging tentative definition _resultbuffer

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@James Dunay ...try this 100% working method.

go to your project profile

-> build settings

-> go to "Search path"

-> go to "Framework search path"

-> now,double click on path located

-> there are two paths like

(1) $(inherited)

(2) "$(SRCROOT)/../../../Data/myCodes/Hello_SOAP 2/edumb/Nav"

-> remove all data of second path..Thats it...

Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Clean your targets, restart XCode, rebuild, try again.